# Custom week calendar with select day and date

Tags: ios, date, calendar

I'm trying to implement this kind of custom weekly calendar, with a date selection with a specific highlighting of the day and date. You can implement this kind. Maybe there are similar or ready-made solutions, thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[After spend some time i found this one](https://github.com/alberdev/DateScrollPicker)